# Creating stored procedure for updating columns by case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, dynamic-sql

I know there are quite a few questions about this but I couldn't find an answer to mine.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+----+--------+--------+----------+
| ID | FormID | ItemID | StrataID |  
+----+--------+--------+----------+
| a  | b      |   1111 | NULL     |  
| a  | b      |   2222 | NULL     |  
| a  | b      |   3333 | NULL     |  
| a  | g      |   4563 | NULL     |  
| b  | f      |   6666 | NULL     |  
+----+--------+--------+----------+
```

I would like to update the values for StrataID based on their ID+FormID+ItemID. The values i would like to insert are not stored in any table in the data base they are just a separated list that I have. 
if i'm using a regular case statement to update the table it looks like this:

```
 UPDATE [Table1]
    SET [StrataID] = 
        CASE ([ItemID])
            when 111  then 1
            when 222 then 2
            when 333 then 5
        else [StrataID]
        END 
WHERE [ID] = 'a'and [FormID] = 'b'
```

So the final result is:

```
+----+--------+--------+----------+--+
| ID | FormID | ItemID | StrataID |  |
+----+--------+--------+----------+--+
| a  | b      |   1111 | 1        |  |
| a  | b      |   2222 | 2        |  |
| a  | b      |   3333 | 5        |  |
| a  | g      |   4563 | NULL     |  |
| b  | f      |   6666 | NULL     |  |
+----+--------+--------+-------
```

But i would like to avoid duplicating the case statement for every FormID because I have over 2000 records to update in this manner.

I tried the following dynamic sql, where @ColumnName are all the available FormID's for a specific ID+FormID and @NewValue is the string of values I would like to insert to the 'StrataID' field instead of the NULLS:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @NewValue AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


SELECT @ColumnName = STUFF((SELECT distinct  ',' +  QUOTENAME(ItemID)
                      FROM [Table1] 
                      where [ID] = 'a'and [FormID] = 'b'
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') , 1, 1, '');

SET @NewValue = ',1,2,5,';


SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 

    'UPDATE [Table1] SET [StrataID] = '+@NewValue+'
     WHERE[ID] = ''a'' and [FormID] = ''b'' AND ItemID ='+@ColumnName+';' 

--Execute the Dynamic Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

When I try to execute it I get an error -

```
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 18
Must declare the scalar variable "@NewValue".
```

I understand that it might be treating @NewValue as as a string and not integers but I am not sure how to store the values that I need to set as the new values differently and how to create a dynamic sql statement from duplicated case statements.

Any advice on how to convert my sql to a dynamic update sql? 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Instead of Exec, print out the created dynamic sql, and let us see what it looks like

Comment: Please take more time to give more details and to provide accurate example. both your code blocks are referencing different tables and neither or complete. Please provide 'print' as stated by @DancingFool , and what you want it to look like using the same tables.

Comment: @DancingFool thank you for your feedback - I have updated mu question to show my input table, required output and error message.

Comment: Where is your list of changes coming from? You say it is not in the DB, but it must come from somewhere - what does the list look like? Does it have a list of FormID and the changes for each one or what? I'm not sure what is supposed to be feeding the dynamic SQL

Comment: checkout the answer I have just submitted. you don't need a dynamic query to handle your scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that everything is `nvarchar` type when concatenating parts to form your dynamic query else you would get errors. Therefore, you should be using the following code rather than what you have right now.

Note that all parameter values are being cast to nvarchar data type in code below.

```
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 

        'UPDATE [Table1] SET [StrataID] = '+ cast(@NewValue as nvarchar(100)) +'
         WHERE[ID] = ''a'' and [FormID] = ''b'' 
           AND ItemID ='+ cast( @ColumnName as nvarchar(500)) +';'
```

However, you don't need a dynamic query to tackle your scenario. Instead follow the approach below.

1. In this approach, you collect all your ItemId values in table
   variable `@ItemValues` and the corresponding StrataId values in a
   table varaible `@StrataIDValues`.
2. Make sure that the order of values in both tables are same, so that
   first record in @ItemValues table corresponds to first record in
   @StrataIdValues table.

   **Update without dynamic query**

   ```
   DECLARE @ItemValues TABLE (
    SequenceNumber int IDENTITY (1, 1),
    ItemID int
   )
   INSERT INTO @ItemValues (ItemID)
   SELECT
    ItemId
   FROM Table1
   WHERE [ID] = 'a'
   AND [FormID] = 'b';

   --populate the corresponding values for StrataID in same sequence as
   --ItemId values in above table
   DECLARE @StrataIDValues TABLE (
     SequenceNumber int IDENTITY (1, 1),
     StrataID int
   )
   INSERT INTO @StrataIDValues (StrataID)
   VALUES (1), (2), (5);

   UPDATE [Table1]
    SET [StrataID] = v.StrataID
    FROM Table1 t
     INNER JOIN (SELECT
                  ItemID,
                  StrataID
               FROM @ItemValues
       INNER JOIN @StrataIDValues
    ON [@ItemValues].SequenceNumber = [@StrataIDValues].SequenceNumber) v
    ON t.ItemID = v.ItemID;
   ```

Comment: thank you for your response! the query you sent is exactly what I needed!!

Answer (score 0):

by looking your query the first thing I noticed is that missing single quote for update column value and ItemID should be IN instead of = because you have more than one column name.
It should be "SET [StrataID] = ''+@NewValue+'' WHERE[ID] = ''a'' and [FormID] = ''b'' [SectionID] = 1 AND ItemID IN '+@ColumnName+';'

Print @DynamicPivotQuery and excute to see what is the actual error. send the actual update statement and error as well to find the issue.